# Can't get "didBeginContact" to work

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, xcode6

I just startet playing around with swift and want to execute something if any of my nodes collide. Obviously I didn't get that working but I Have no clue why. Read the Documentation a few times but it's mostly written for Objective-C and honestly I think I did not understand it.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

  var eyeset = 0
  var eyes: [SKSpriteNode] = []

  override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
      /* Called when a touch begins */

      for touch: AnyObject in touches {

          let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

          if (eyeset < 9) {

              eyes.insert(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "eye"), atIndex: eyeset)
              eyes[eyeset].xScale = 0.25
              eyes[eyeset].yScale = 0.25
              eyes[eyeset].position = location
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: eyes[eyeset].size.height/2)
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.dynamic = true
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.affectedByGravity = true

              self.addChild(eyes[eyeset])
              eyeset++
          }
          else if (eyeset < 10) {

              eyes.insert(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "eye"), atIndex: eyeset)
              eyes[eyeset].xScale = 0.5
              eyes[eyeset].yScale = 0.5
              eyes[eyeset].position = location
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: eyes[eyeset].size.height/2)
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 1
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.dynamic = true
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.angularDamping = 1
              eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false

              self.addChild(eyes[eyeset])
              eyeset++
          }
          else {
              eyes[eyeset-1].runAction(SKAction.moveTo(location, duration: 0.25))
          }
      }
  }

  func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact!) {
      println("Muttermäßig")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For contact detection to work, you have to set the `contactTestBitMask` property of `SKPhysicsBody`.

```
eyes[eyeset].physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 1
```

`CollisionBitMask` specifies which bodies can collide with each other in the physics environment, whereas the `contactTestBitMask` defines the categories of physics bodies for which the contact delegate methods will get called when the node intersects with them.

Read up on the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/contactTestBitMask).

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but the function on didBeginContact is still not firing. What else am I missing?

Comment: I got it. I did initialized any physicsWorld... I apologize for that faux pas. Thanks a lot